# Count must be a DbConstantExpression or a DbParameterReferenceExpression. Parameter name: Count

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, dbcontext

```
Dim days = (From d In db.ShiftSchedule _
               Where d.Shift1 = 1 And d.WorkDate >= StartDate _
               Order By d.ID _
               Skip SkipValue _
               Select New With {d.ID, d.WorkDate, d.Shift1, _
               .EndDate = (From dd In db.ShiftSchedule _
               Where d.Shift1 = 1 And d.WorkDate >= StartDate _
               Order By d.ID _
               Skip SkipValue - 1 _
               Select dd.WorkDate).First}).First
```

When i try to execute the LINQ to Entities query above, i get the following error, what could be wrong with that code.

> Count must be a DbConstantExpression or a DbParameterReferenceExpression. Parameter name: Count

Comment: Try to use `FirstOrDefault` in your inner query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, Your inner query should have condition as 
Where **dd**.Shift1 = 1 And **dd**.WorkDate >= StartDate Order By **dd**.ID 
instead of, 
Where d.Shift1 = 1 And d.WorkDate >= StartDate _ 
               Order By d.ID

I am not sure if it's a typo..

Answer (score 0):

Since the value for "Skip" you are providing is calculated, this will lead to the exception. If you store the value in a variable that you calculate first and then use the variable, it should work as expected.

So

```
Dim actualSkipValue = SkipValue - 1

Dim days = (From d In db.ShiftSchedule _
               Where d.Shift1 = 1 And d.WorkDate >= StartDate _
               Order By d.ID _
               Skip SkipValue _
               Select New With {d.ID, d.WorkDate, d.Shift1, _
               .EndDate = (From dd In db.ShiftSchedule _
               Where d.Shift1 = 1 And d.WorkDate >= StartDate _
               Order By d.ID _
               Skip actualSkipValue _
               Select dd.WorkDate).First}).First
```

should not throw the exception.